# asp.net Core 2.1 MVC validators not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following page:

```
@model LogonModel
<div class="login-modal modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Welcome</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    @foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState)
                    {
                        <ul><li>@Html.ValidationMessage(modelState.Key, modelState.Value)</li></ul>
                    }
                </div>
            }

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Contact us now.</a></p>

                    <form asp-action="Login" class="login-form">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="validation-summary text-danger"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                            <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-default login-submit" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" asp-for="RememberUser">
                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="RememberUser">Remember my account details</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="#">Login using a subscription ID</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Originally the post to the controller was simply on the submit button and the validators worked. i.e. leave out the email and the validator would display an error message. For other reasons. When I press the submit button I call a jQuery function before going off to my controller and in my javascript the first thing I do is:

```
var loginForm = $(".login-form");

    if (loginForm.valid()) {…..
```

This seems not to work, because even when I leave email off for example, my javascript gets called, and it still goes through the code in my 'if' statement.

What do I need to do to make the validators work again?

Comment: can you do the validation in `LogonModel` model?

Comment: If I place `[Required]` on the property on the model, it still get's ignored

Comment: Have you checked in console? any error in console?as per my knowledge  because of jquery errors validation can not fire.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Validation is only triggered once an input has been focused/modified or when the form is *actually* submitted (your code is running before that). In either case, The `valid` method only reports on the states of inputs that validation has been triggered on. In other words, it's possible for it to return `true` even if required inputs are empty, if those have yet to be validated.

Long and short, you need to call `validate`, first, to trigger a full form validation.

```
loginForm.validate();
if (loginForm.valid()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me, but if I use `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(loginForm);` it does

Comment: So I've now got validation working to ensure an email and password are entered. But, if the wrong values are entered, in the controller I add an error to the ModelState Error's collection, these are not being shown, even if I call either of the above in my Success block.

Comment: Are you submitting via AJAX? If so, you'll need to manually handle the display of any validation errors returned from that. It won't happen automatically for you, unless it goes back to the server to render the full view again (i.e. normal form post).